# Finding local maxima

Tags: javascript, statistics

I'd like to find the local maxima for a set of data.
I have a log of flight data from a sounding rocket payload, and I'd like to find the approximate times for the staging based on accelerometer data. I should be able to get the times I want based on a visual inspection of the data on a graph, but how would I go about finding the points programmatically in Javascript?

Comment: Loop through the data. Whenever the next element is lower than the previous, the previous one was a local max.

Comment: There is a significant amount of noise in my signal. The staging is not exactly clean, either. Rocket engines don't just stop, they tend to sputter, and the actual separation of stages sends shocks through the payload compartment. I can't use an approach that simple.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a filter to smooth the data first. I guess you'll need to do some research on filtering. Once you've done that, post your code if it doesn't work and we'll try to help you. SO is not for getting others to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only necessary to know approximate times, probably it's good enough to use some heuristic such as: run the data through a smoothing filter and then look for jumps.

If it's important to find the staging times accurately, my advice is to construct a piecewise continuous model and fit that to the data, and then derive the staging times from that. For example, a one-stage model might be: for 0 < t < t_1, acceleration is f(t) - g; for t > t_1, acceleration is - g, where g is gravitational acceleration. I don't know what f(t) might be here but presumably it's well-known in rocket engineering. The difficulty of fitting such a model is due to the presence of the cut-off point t_1, which makes it nondifferentiable, but it's not really too difficult; in a relatively simple case like this, you can loop over the possible cut-off points and compute the least-squares solution for the rest of the parameters, then take the cut-off point or points which have the least error.

See Seber and Wild, "Nonlinear Regression"; there is a chapter about such models.